# 2SXC App and Content modules have different version numbers after upgrade. Can't repair upgrade or upgrade to latest version

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

DNN 7.4.2

Over a year ago, we upgraded from 2SXC 8.8.0 to 9.2.0. The upgrade took a really long time because have a pretty big DNN instance with many portals. We only use 2SXC on a couple of portals, though. Once the upgrade completed, App was still stuck on 8.8.0 while Content was fine at 9.2.0. At that time, we just left it as it was because we don't use App.

We're looking to upgrade 2SXC to the latest version (at the time of writing this, that version is 9.33.0) but if I try to repair the 9.2.0 or upgrade to 9.33.0, I get an error. See below.

[image]

```
StartJob    Starting Installation
Info    Starting Installation - 2SexyContent
Info    Starting Installation - Script
Info    Begin Sql execution
Info    Creating backup of previous version - SqlDataProvider\Uninstall.SqlDataProvider
Failure ExceptionSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'M:\inetpub\myspecialwebsite\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SqlDataProvider\Uninstall.SqlDataProvider' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.SetAttributes(String path, FileAttributes fileAttributes) at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.FileSystemUtils.CopyFile(String sourceFileName, String destFileName) at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Internal.RetryableAction.TryIt() at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Util.CopyFile(InstallFile installFile, String basePath, Logger log) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.FileInstaller.InstallFile(InstallFile insFile)
Info    Finished Sql execution
Failure Installation Failed - Script
Info    Installation Failed - 2SexyContent
Info    Starting Installation - 2SexyContent-App
Info    Starting Installation - Module
Info    Module registered successfully - 2sxc-app
Info    Component installed successfully - Module
Info    Starting Installation - File
Info    Creating backup of previous version - icon-app.png
Failure ExceptionSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'M:\inetpub\myspecialwebsite\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\icon-app.png' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.SetAttributes(String path, FileAttributes fileAttributes) at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.FileSystemUtils.CopyFile(String sourceFileName, String destFileName) at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Internal.RetryableAction.TryIt() at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Util.CopyFile(InstallFile installFile, String basePath, Logger log) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.FileInstaller.InstallFile(InstallFile insFile)
Failure Installation Failed - File
Info    Rolling back component install - Module
Info    Component rolled back successfully - Module
Info    Installation Failed - 2SexyContent-App
Info    Starting Installation - 2sic_Imazen_ImageResizerPro
Info    Starting Installation - Script
Info    Begin Sql execution
Info    Finished Sql execution
Info    Component installed successfully - Script
Info    Starting Installation - Assembly
Info    Assembly already registered - bin\ImageResizer.dll
Info    Assembly registered - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dll
Info    Creating backup of previous version - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dll
Failure ExceptionSystem.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'M:\inetpub\myspecialwebsite\bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dll' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.SetAttributes(String path, FileAttributes fileAttributes) at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.FileSystemUtils.CopyFile(String sourceFileName, String destFileName) at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.Internal.RetryableAction.TryIt() at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Util.CopyFile(InstallFile installFile, String basePath, Logger log) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.FileInstaller.InstallFile(InstallFile insFile)
Failure Installation Failed - Assembly
Info    Rolling back component install - Script
Info    Component rolled back successfully - Script
Info    Installation Failed - 2sic_Imazen_ImageResizerPro
Info    Deleted temporary install folder
EndJob  Installation Failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing IIS_IUSRS (default IIS user) in the folder so my colleague added it and it resolved the issue.